# Error in changing a row name of a data frame: target of assignment expands to non-language object

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a set of data frames, where they have respectively different number of rows.(data frames: seg1 through seg10)
But after the `rbind` process, the last row name becomes a number that I'd like to change into 'center' character, and here's what I tried.

```
for (i in 1:10){
  assign( paste( "seg", i, sep="" ), rbind( kth_df[ kth_km$cluster ==i, ], kth_km$centers[ i, ] ) )
  last_row <- dim( get( paste( "seg", i, sep="" ) ) )[1]
  rownames( get( paste( "seg", i, sep="" ) ) )[last_row] <- "center"
}
```

but this gives me

> 'target of assignment expands to non-language object'

error at the last sentence. I can't figure out what I did wrong and how I should change the code.
Thanks for your help!

```
 kth_df where cluster segment is 1
      1100  1111  1123  1126
1     2      3     4     0
2     3      0     1     2
```

And `kth_km` is a list coming after `kmeans` clustering on the data. So I want to add 'center' vector at the last row like

```
kth_df
      1100  1111  1123  1126
1     2     3     4     0
2     3     0     1     2
3     2.5   1.5    2.5    1
```

And then change the last row name as 'center'.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your data? It's not clear what kth_km and kth_df refer to, among other things.

Comment: @Juan Bosco  I did, and hope you could understand what Im trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
get("iris")[1] <- 1
```

You'll get the same error you are getting.

Now try this variation of your code.

```
for (i in 1:10){
  my_name <- paste("seg", i, sep = "")
  assign(my_name, rbind(i, i*i))
  last_row <- dim(get(my_name))[1]
  print(last_row)
  rownames( get(my_name) )[last_row] <- "center"
}
```

You'll get the following error that (I think) explains why your code is not working.

> Error in rownames(get(my_name))[last_row] <- "center" :    could not
>   find function "get<-"

A solution would be to create a list of data frames.

```
list_of_df <- lapply (1:10, function(i)){
  a_df <- rbind(kth_df[kth_km$cluster == i, ], kth_km$centers[i, ])
  last_row <- dim(a_df)[1]
  rownames(a_df)[last_row] <- "center"
  a_df
}
```

If you want them named.

```
names() <- paste0("seg", 1:10)
```